Passing JSON data, back from a cloud function
The issue I am having concerns the cloud function hereafter.
The problem is in the dbRef.once({}) block. The traces observed due to the logs (i.e console.log(...)) are as expected. Having either "Node exists:..." or "Node DOES-NOT exist:..." showing up in the logs.
But the allUsers.push(userData); instead is never taken into account (i.e. ignored).
Why is that ? Am I missing something ?
If I put allUsers.push(userData); outside the block, inside the forEach, it works perfectly.
exports.listSelectedUsers = onRequest({cors: [corsAllow]}, (req, res) => {
  let jsonResult;
  const allUsers = [{}];
  admin.auth().listUsers()
    .then(function(listUsersResult) {
      listUsersResult.users.forEach(function(userRecord) {
        const refStr = "MyDBRoot/SectionTwo/SubSectionOne/"+userRecord.uid;
        const dbRef = admin.database().ref(refStr);

        dbRef.once("value").then((snapshot) => {
          if (snapshot.exists()) {
            console.log("Node exists: "+userRecord.uid);
            const userData = userRecord.toJSON();
            allUsers.push(userData);
          } else console.log("Node DOES-NOT exist: "+userRecord.uid);
        });

      });

      jsonResult = {users: allUsers};
      res.status(200).send(jsonResult);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log("Error listing users:", error);
      res.status(500).send(error);
    });
}); /* End of listSelectedUsers */

I understand that a synchronization issue is taking place here.
But I don't quite see how to solve it. Since I want to have every selected user. I need to do something for each (one) user inside the foreach loop. But I also would like to send back the result only after all selected user have been processed. Therefore after the foreach loop. I tried to stick a .then after the foreach but that does not seem to work. This must be where I am doing something wrong.

The problem here is that all data from Firebase comes back asynchronously, so your jsonResult = {users: allUsers}; runs before the allUsers.push(userData); ever runs. If you add some logging, you can see that in the order of the output. This problem with asynchrohnous data access is very common and the solution is always the same: the code that needs the data has to be inside the then callback, be called from there, or otherwise synchronized.

A common way to handle asynchronous behavior nowadays is by using the async / await keywords. I recommend reading https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous, https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions, and watchibng the video series in that last page.
